# i can not add a C++ source file to an empty project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Ok, Im new to programming in C++ and I was going to try my hand at Directx game programming. I tried to create an empty project and when i right click on the source file in the solution explorer to add a new C++ source file, its not showing up in the add new item menu.Can someon help?

Comment: What compiler?  What development environment?  C++ runs *everywhere*.

Comment: Have retagged this with Visual Studio.  It's obviously that, because of the term "Solution Explorer" and "Add New Item" menu...  And for the probable assumption that C++ == Visual Studio ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure starting with DirectX is the best way to learn C++...

Answer (score 2):

Don't right-click on the solution in the explorer.  Go one level down the tree to your project.  If you right-click the project you should get the correct 'add new item' menu.

You can also highlight anything in your project, and click File->New->File (or press Ctrl-N).  You can even create sources outside Visual Studio and drag/drop them onto your project in the solution explorer.

Just a heads-up...  Make sure you have a good handle on the basics before you try making games.

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu "Project" then "Add new item" then select "Visual C++" then "Code" then "C++ source file"

You can also right click on the project name (not solution) then "Add..." "New item..." and so on.

I'm reinstalling Visual Studio right now because the VS 2012 RC installation broke my previous VS2008 install so I can't check, but this is what I can remember right now. Sorry if that is not exactly the way you do it.